# SQL Server 2005 Sleep_Task Wait Type

Tags: sql-server

I have recently encountered a wait type that I am unable to find much info for. I have a stored procedure that takes about 1.0 hour to run but when the connection in the activity monitor displays the Sleep_Task wait type the SP could run for days if I didn't kill it. It just sits there doing nothing.

Does anyone have any info on what this wait type is and why it occurs?

Thanks,

Chris
DBA

Comment: Could you post the stored procedure?  Or describe in detail what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I thought this was a deadlock, but BOL says:

> Sleep_Task Occurs when a task sleeps
>   while waiting for a generic event to
>   occur.

Someone on SqlServerCentral posts:

> They are always associated with a
>   processID that has the status of
>   suspended.

Are you using distributed transactions?

It seems to be a known issue in pre-SP2 SqlServer2005:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/942fe3d4-141a-486a-afdf-53f079d3a4d3

Comment: The documentation on this seems very sparse.

Comment: No, Not using Distributed Transactions.

Comment: @wcm - [Some cases where this can crop up mentioned here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11831/3690)